# windows service for data insertion

Tags: asp.net

I have created windows service for data-insertion.Time interval is one min.After one min, data insert into table.Data get inserted into table at multiple time.I don't want to that,only one time.How to do that?May I need to check in database wether entry is there or nor if not add.

Comment: Yes, if you don't need duplicate data, fist check and then insert

Comment: Service is calling after every one minute. You can check data before inserting into table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query before inserting the data.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE Name = @Name)
 RETURN
```

-- here, after the check, do the INSERT
You might also want to create a UNIQUE INDEX on your Name column to make sure no two rows with the same value exist:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UIX_Name
ON dbo.YourTable(Name)
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

//You can do like this in ur code

```
if (ChkRecordExist() == true)
        {
            //Do nothing
        }
        else               
        {
             // insert operation     
        }

protected bool ChkRecordExist()
    {    
       //here logic for record exist or not.
      //if record is exist return true else return false
    }
```